# Chromium browser showing blank page when transition from page to page

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

I'm running Chromium in kiosk mode in armbian using the following command:

```
chromium 'http://localhost/'
--window-position=0,0
--start-fullscreen
--kiosk
--noerrdialogs
--disable-translate
--no-first-run
--fast
--fast-start
--disable-infobars
--disable-features=TranslateUI
--disk-cache-dir=/var/www/
--disable-pinch
--overscroll-history-navigation=0
--disable-features=TouchpadOverscrollHistoryNavigation
--enable-logging --v=1
--window-size=1366,768
```

However, I'm experiencing a blank page transition issue when navigating from one page to another (for example, from page 1 to page 2). I have tried using other browsers, and the issue doesn't occur. Additionally, when I access the localhost IP from my PC, I don't encounter the blank transition problem."

VIDEO:
https://streamable.com/o8o2be